# Angular OKTA authentication always returns false

Tags: angular, okta, okta-signin-widget

I have followed this documentation to create a test app
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/

1. I am able to see OKTA Sign in page
2. After entering valid credentials it struck at http://localhost:4200/login/callback?code=xxxxxxxx&state=xxxxxxxxx
3. 

```
this.isAuthenticated$ = this._oktaStateService.authState$.pipe(
      filter((s: AuthState) => !!s),
      map((s: AuthState) => {
        console.log(s);
        return s.isAuthenticated ?? false}

      )
    );
```

is returning false always

I have added http://localhost:4200 as Trusted Origins

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to figure out ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the callback route pointing to the `OktaCallbackComponent`?
See [docs for handling the callback](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/#handle-the-callback-from-okta).

You can also see an example Angular app using Okta redirect [in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/okta-samples/okta-angular-quickstart).

Comment: Yes. I have added call back. Jere is repo https://gitlab.com/nchakilam/angular-okta/-/tree/develop

Comment: You don't have a `router-outlet` defined in the AppComponent, so the `OktaCallbackComponent` doesn't get called. Please add a `router-outlet`.

Comment: Seems likes there is an issue with how okta handles callback when you trigger signIn right when page loads and not on a signin click. When I do it with signin click, I am logged in, but when I redirect right when app loads. It goes into loop cause authstate does not return true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using okta with angular (v13):
"@okta/okta-angular": "^6.0.0",
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^7.0.2",

And I had same issue on my onInit, isAuthenticated never returning true.
What curious_debugger posted above there was really happening with my app.

I was able to solve this issue by adding oktaStateService and subscribe authState

```
 this.isAuthenticated$ = this.oktaStateService.authState$.pipe(
      filter((s: AuthState) => !!s),
      map((s: AuthState) => s.isAuthenticated ?? false)
    );

 this.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
      this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
 ...
```

Hope this help, let me know if it makes sense.
Thanks